# uint32_t or uint64_t for linux counter

Tags: linux

I am working on a Linux counter which should count all installed Linux machines (all linux kernel based, that is including Android and so on) to date (and in the future). Here's what I've got:

```
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
     uint32_t num_linux_machines = count_current_linux_machines();

     while (1) {
        wait_for_next_linux_machine_installed();
        num_linux_machines++;
     }
}
```

Don't worry about the `count()` and `wait()` functions, I'll do that later. The question is: Do you think that `uint32_t` will be sufficient for the next, say 5 years or should I use `uint64_t` right away instead? Thanks for any insights ;)

The real question that would be harder to answer is how to implement the two missing functions (that is which heuristics to use).

Comment: What machines do you want to count? All which are existing on the world? How do yo intend to count them?

Comment: Interesting question. There should be statistical methods to do this but I'm not so good at mathematics. The fun at it is that the question (wheter 2**32 would suffice) arises at all meanwhile. Originally this was meant as a joke question, sorry for some reason I couldn't add the fun tag ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A 64-bit counter only consumes 4 additional bytes, so why not? It's not like 4 more bytes will bloat the program.

Answer (score 2):

Uint32 will overflow around 2017 according to [this story](http://news.yahoo.com/total-shipments-android-phones-surpass-1-billion-2013-230036024.html).